# Plot categorical data as histogram/ bar in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I am new to R and have been trying for a few days to plot histogram / bar chart to view the trend. I have this categorical variable : countryx and coded it into 1,2,3. 
I have tried these 2 scripts below and got error messages as follows :

## Output 1: blank chart with x and y axis, no stack/bar trend

```
qplot(DI$countryx,geom = "histogram",ylab = "count",
xlab = "countryx",binwidth=5,colour=I("blue"),fill=I("wheat"))
```

## Output 2: error message- ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class integer

```
ggplot(DI$countryX, aes(x=countryx)) 
+ geom_bar(aes(y=count), stat = "count",position ="stack",...,
width  =5,aes=true)
```

Appreciate for all advice. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To plot histogram with`qplot`you just pass it the variable, don't need to add `geom=histogram`. If you give `qplot` one variable it will plot a histogram by default. Another thing, you need to specify `data=`, so if you dataframe name is `DI` and you want to plot `countryX` variable from it then `qplot (countryX, data=DI,....)`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems with your code. `ggplot` takes a dataframe, not a vector, but you're supplying a vector. Try this

```
ggplot(DI, aes(x=countryx, y = count)) + geom_col(width = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @yeedle mentioned you need a data.frame (maybe use `as.data.frame`)
How about:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(countryx = rep(1:3), count = rbinom(3,10,0.3))
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = countryx, y = count)) + ylab("count")
p + geom_col(aes(x = countryx, fill = factor(countryx)))
```

[image]